# CISCO 2960X Access Switch Issue Random Limited Connectivity Issue

Tags: networking, local-area-network, cisco-catalyst

I have a CISCO 2960X Access switch which is configured in 8 Stack.

IOS Version 15.0.2EX4 Software Image: C2960X-UniversalK9-M

The System is connected VIA the CISCO IP Phone (7942G)and and then terminated to the Switch (Including the Patch Panel).

But I am facing a lot of Limited connectivity Issue, as the IP Phone is Working Fine during this issue.

Cannot figure out the problem and its happening randomly on all systems and some times the issue is resolved automatically.

I have performed below step to rectify the issue with no results.

1. Checked the cable connectivity via the LAN Tester and it is OK.
2. Updated system LAN drives through dell update utility and is latest.
3. System replaced with a new system.
4. Replaced CISCO IP Phone ( as the system is connected VIA CISCO Phone).
5. Switch port configuration is similar to the other switches.
6. Windows OS 7 Professional 64 Bit.

The issue gets resolved temporarily only if I change the cable to the another port on the same switch.

I have a another office in the same building which is using the 2960S Series of Access which does not face any issue.

Both The Offices are connected to the same DHCP & DNS Server.

Comment: It sounds like the switch itself is faulty.  Do you have SMARTnet on the switch?

Comment: You haven't actually described your problem. What does `But I am facing a lot of Limited connectivity Issue` mean?

Comment: sorry for that @ joeqwerty the limited acess i am facing is on the System itself. but the IP phone on the same port if working fine

Comment: Again, we don't know what `limited access` means in this context. What do you mean?

Comment: No Internet access on the system

Comment: @ armani I do not have SMARTnet support

Comment: I would check the phone. Check to see if it has the correct and/or updated firmware. Remember the phone is a switch itself.

Comment: @BadDos I found out that when I remove the command from the switch for that particular port the phone and the system can communicate. Command : ( IP verify source).